# convert RDD Array[Any] = Array(List([String], ListBuffer([string])) to RDD(String, Seq[String])

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with `Any` type, example:

```
Array(List(Mathematical Sciences, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic)))
```

I want to convert it to RDD of type `RDD[(String, Seq[String])]`

I tried:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(strList)
case class X(titleId: String, terms: List[String])

val df = rdd.map { case Array(s0, s1) => X(s0, s1) }.toDF()
```

I passed a long time to try without success

Comment: i want convert rdd type Array(List([String], ListBuffer([string])) to RDD(String, Seq[String])   example : Array(List(Mathematical Sciences, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic))) I want to convert it to rdd Array(Mathematical Sciences, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic))

Comment: there is a gray 'edit' button in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
val result: RDD[(String, Seq[String])] = 
  rdd.map { case List(s0: String, s1: ListBuffer[String]) =>  (s0, s1) }
```

But note that any record in the input `RDD[Any]` that doesn't match these types (that can't be checked in compile time) would throw a `scala.MatchError`.

Comment: i execute your code , i have error : scala> val result: RDD[(String, Seq[String])] = 
     |   rdd.map { case List(s0: String, s1: ListBuffer[String]) =>  (s0, s1) }
<console>:32: error: not found: type RDD
       val result: RDD[(String, Seq[String])] =
                   ^
<console>:33: error: not found: type ListBuffer
         rdd.map { case List(s0: String, s1: ListBuffer[String]) =>  (s0, s1) }

Comment: i have a list as : List(List(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)), List(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)), List(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation,  characteristics)))

Comment: i transform it ti rdd : Array[Any] = Array(List(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)), List(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)), List(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation,  characteristics)))

Comment: i want to have ca rdd :Array(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)),(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)),(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation,  characteristics))) type RDD[String , Seq[String])

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, if you have

```
val strList = Array(List("Mathematical Sciences", ListBuffer("applications", "asymptotic", "largest", "enable", "stochastic")))
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(strList)
```

which is of following *dataTypes*

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[java.io.Serializable]]
```

You can convert it to your required *dataTypes*

```
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[String])]
```

by simply using `map` and *converting the dataTypes* as

```
rdd.map(x => (x(0).toString, x(1).asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[String]].toSeq))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I execute you code , i have this error in spark                                      scala> rdd.map(x => (x(0).toString, x(1).asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[String]].toSeq))
<console>:33: error: Any does not take parameters
       rdd.map(x => (x(0).toString, x(1).asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[String]].toSeq))
                      ^
<console>:33: error: Any does not take parameters
       rdd.map(x => (x(0).toString, x(1).asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[String]].toSeq))

Comment: my list is List(List(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)), List(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)), List(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation,  characteristics)))

Comment: i transform it to rdd i have :Array[Any] = Array(List(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)), List(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)), List(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation,  characteristics)))

Comment: i want to have : Array(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)),(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)),(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation,  characteristics))) type RDD[String , Seq[String])

Comment: have you idee please

Comment: Did you read my answer carefully? If you have data like `List(List(a9000038, ListBuffer(applications, asymptotic, largest, enable, stochastic, stochastic)), List(a9000031, ListBuffer(loci, loci, formal, meet,size)), List(a9000006, ListBuffer(exploitation, exploitation, exploitation, characteristics)))` how do you have `Array[Any]` when you convert it to rdd? you should have `RDD[List[java.io.Serializable]]` as I clearly explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , it s worked
i have a warning but worked

val rdd = sc.makeRDD(strList)

val result = rdd.map { case List(s0: String, s1: Seq[String]) =>  (s0, s1) }

:32: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern Seq[String] (the underlying of Seq[String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       val result = rdd.map { case List(s0: String, s1: Seq[String]) =>  (s0, s1) }
                                                        ^
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[1051] at map at :32

thank you